# Explanation to why connection = null in JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc

Every time I check out a tutorial for JDBC programmers seem to set the connection as null

```
 Connection conn = null;
```

and I can't figure out why. Can someone clarify this for me?

Comment: It's a workaround for the `variable 'conn' might not have been initialized` compiler error. It's a common practice for more than just JDBC. However, it's usually better to use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it's so the `finally` block can include a check like

```
} finally {
    // ...
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Without the default initialization to `null`, you'd get an error that `conn` might not have been initialized.

Comment: People should use try-with-resources instead.